# Python: Entire Script 1 Tab backwards?

Tags: python, python-idle

I want to shift back the entire code 1 tab backwards. Is that possible? What is the key commbination? I am using Idle 3.6.3 on an Mac OSX System.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: That is entirely a question about your editor, and nothing to do with Python.

Comment: okay... can you answer?

Comment: I agree with @DanielRoseman, but anyway for me is Shift+Tab after selecting the code.

Comment: We don't know what IDE you are using and you want someone to answer?

Comment: which IDE are you using???

Comment: i am using the newest one: 3.6.3

Comment: That is not an answer to the question "which editor are you using".

Comment: The question was answered by adding the python-idle tag.

Answer (score 3):

Whilst it's absolutely a question about your editor rather than Python, many editors actually use the same key combo for this. On my Mac, it's the same in VS-Code, Sublime3 and TextMate:

1. `cmd-a` to select all text (or select a smaller region if you prefer)
2. `cmd-[` to un-indent the selected block one stop (and `cmd-]` to indent)

Here's a video I made demonstrating the process in TextMate on a MacBook Pro:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyHRi2xXAnA

Comment: Thanks :D, but that's not working for my laptop. You know the keys there? I have an macbook...

Comment: I added a screen capture demonstrating the key strokes on a Macbook using TextMate.

Comment: Control-a, control-[, and control-] work the same for IDLE on Windows, so I presume the Command (cmd) versions should work for IDLE on Mac.